# How to close boxy window on press ESC key?

Tags: jquery-plugins, boxy

I'm using http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/

How to close boxy window on press ESC key?

Comment: Problem solved... That is my mistake...

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (this.options.closeable) {
            jQuery(document.body).bind('keypress.boxy', function(evt) {
                var key = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
                if (key == 27) {
                    self.hide();
                    jQuery(document.body).unbind('keypress.boxy');
                }
            });
        }
```